# Add highlights to span's from pregenerated html

Tags: java, android, html

Hello i can't figure out how to use the span's that are in the styledText String and add highlights to only the words in those span's.
The current styledText String is an example of the code i recieve from another application.
The highlighting of the spans needs to happen automatically.
Does anyone know how best to do this?

```
    public class ArticleActivity extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

        TextView textview = new TextView(this);

        String styledText = "Vanwege een verdacht koffertje <span id=\"txt8264:idx8:tkn41:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">is</span> vanochtend een tankstation langs <span id=\"txt8264:idx18:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> A16 bij Hazeldonk korte tijd afgesloten <span id=\"txt8264:idx32:tkn1156:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">geweest</span>.<br/><br/>Volgens <span id=\"txt8264:idx37:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> politie stapte een man uit zijn auto en zette hij <span id=\"txt8264:idx59:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> koffertje naast <span id=\"txt8264:idx65:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> tankstation neer. Daarna reed hij weg.<br/><br/>Een explosievenverkenner van <span id=\"txt8264:idx87:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> politie onderzocht <span id=\"txt8264:idx93:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> koffertje en constateerde dat <span id=\"txt8264:idx103:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> leeg was. <span id=\"txt8264:idx110:tkn66:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">Het</span> tankstation werd korte tijd later weer vrijgegeven. <span id=\"txt8264:idx127:tkn25:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">De</span> afsluiting <span id=\"txt8264:idx131:tkn404:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">had</span> geen gevolgen voor <span id=\"txt8264:idx139:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> verkeer op <span id=\"txt8264:idx145:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> A16 bij <span id=\"txt8264:idx151:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> grensovergang met België.<br/><br/>Ook <span id=\"txt8264:idx162:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> parkeerplaats achter <span id=\"txt8264:idx168:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> tankstation <span id=\"txt8264:idx172:tkn215:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">was</span> bereikbaar.<br/><br/>";

        textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        setContentView(textview);               
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best/only way i have found to work is using a webview with inline html/css.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = new WebView(this);        
        String styledText = "Vanwege een verdacht koffertje <span id=\"txt8264:idx8:tkn41:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">is</span> vanochtend een tankstation langs <span id=\"txt8264:idx18:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> A16 bij Hazeldonk korte tijd afgesloten <span id=\"txt8264:idx32:tkn1156:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">geweest</span>.<br/><br/>Volgens <span id=\"txt8264:idx37:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> politie stapte een man uit zijn auto en zette hij <span id=\"txt8264:idx59:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> koffertje naast <span id=\"txt8264:idx65:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> tankstation neer. Daarna reed hij weg.<br/><br/>Een explosievenverkenner van <span id=\"txt8264:idx87:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> politie onderzocht <span id=\"txt8264:idx93:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> koffertje en constateerde dat <span id=\"txt8264:idx103:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> leeg was. <span id=\"txt8264:idx110:tkn66:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">Het</span> tankstation werd korte tijd later weer vrijgegeven. <span id=\"txt8264:idx127:tkn25:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">De</span> afsluiting <span id=\"txt8264:idx131:tkn404:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">had</span> geen gevolgen voor <span id=\"txt8264:idx139:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> verkeer op <span id=\"txt8264:idx145:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> A16 bij <span id=\"txt8264:idx151:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> grensovergang met België.<br/><br/>Ook <span id=\"txt8264:idx162:tkn4:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">de</span> parkeerplaats achter <span id=\"txt8264:idx168:tkn98:cls11\" class=\"supported dictionary\">het</span> tankstation <span id=\"txt8264:idx172:tkn215:cls1\" class=\"supported dictionary\">was</span> bereikbaar.<br/><br/>";
        final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.append("<html>");
        html.append("<head>");
        html.append("<style type='text/css'>  body .supported{background-color:#00A4E4;}  </style>");
        html.append("</head>");
        html.append("<body>");
        html.append("<h1>Some Heading</h1>");
        html.append(styledText.toString());
        html.append("</body></html>");
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");           
        setContentView(webView);
        }
```